# Adding ground to workbench

Tags: grounding, workbench

I've got question for you folks.

I've recently moved into my new apartment and I'm setting up my workbench (scope, PSU, function generator, etc.) again. But I have a teensy weensy little problem. Since the apartment is in a 1930s renovated building, there's barely any grounding done in the house. Only the shared kitchen and laundry room have grounded sockets, but my room only has the following ones:

[image: Wall socket without grounding]

Now obviously for safety reasons I would prefer to ground my whole workbench.

I've checked all wall sockets and sadly there aren't any ground wires hidden behind the wall. The only place I found one is above my ceiling lamp on the other side of my room.

Do I truly have to pull a wire all the way across my room just to add ground to the wall socket?
Or is there another way I could do it?

My landlord has got faith in my capabilities of being able to fix it myself, as long as it doesn't cost him any money.

Thanks for your help!

p.s. I'm an electrician and electrical engineer, according to my MBO and HBO (dutch education system) diplomas

Comment: Are there still countries where this is even legal?

Comment: @PMF:  Most contries don't force you to go in and replace the wiring every time the electrical code changes.  If the wiring met code when  it was installed (or even installed before there was an official electrical code,) then it is perfectly legal.  That's not to say it is safe, but it can well be legal.

Comment: @PMF only newly built or renovated buildings after 1995 are mandatory to have grounded sockets. And let's just say this building hasn't been renovated in a while

Comment: @DerekLF:  It may not be allowed for you to make changes to the house's electrical wiring.  In some countries, a landlord is required to have electrical wiring done by an electrician.  The landlord allowing you (as a non-electrician) to fiddle with the wiring is the same as the landlord fiddling with the wiring.

Comment: @DerekLF In which country this is, and why do you and your landlord think it is legal for non-electricians to do any electrical work at all? If you rented an apartment from the landlord, and the landlord does not own the whole building (e.g. apartment building, terraced house), the landlord cannot give you permission to do any electrical work either, it's the entity that owns the building, and even if laymen were allowed to do electrical work, the building ownerd cannot take the risk so you really want a permit to allow an electrician to update the wiring.

Comment: @JRE that's the fun part, even though I'm still studying at the university I am a full fledged electrician and electrical engineer. According to my MBO and HBO (dutch education system) i've already finished

Comment: @DerekLF OK you should have mentioned you are an electrician. Sorry to ask but you should then already know how to do the grounding and how to do it legally and if you need a master electrician to approve your work after you have wired it. Otherwise it will be an illegal installation and if anything happens, the insurance company can be quite intersted who made and signed off some faulty electrical work.

Comment: @DerekLF:  I can't tell if that is sufficient.  I just wanted to make sure that you are aware there may be legal problems.  If you are are aware of them, and know what you are doing, then that's fine.

Comment: @DerekLF On the surface, it appears to me that you are in a far, far better position to know what to do. You are there, you can put eyes-on to the situation, you can discuss with the landlord, you can visit local authorities, etc. Everything there is to be known, you have direct access. Yet you seem to be asking people who aren't there, can't drill into the problem on their own, and have only here a few words to rely on. I'm not sure why you are asking, I guess. What's the actual question here? Or is this perfunctory to only say you've exhausted this source, too, before moving forward?